# Get Alt="" value from the selected radio button with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following radio buttons within a PHP loop:

```
<form>
  <table class="table table-bordered optionsChk">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"> Select Bench for case </td>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($db->getRecordSet($sql) as $bench){ ;?>
    <tr>
      <td class="w5">
        <input type="radio" alt="<?php echo($bench['lbl']); ?>" value="<?php echo($bench['sno']); ?>" name="b_sno" id="b_<?php echo($bench['sno']); ?>">
      </td>
      <td class="w95"> <label for="b_<?php echo($bench['sno']); ?>"><?php echo($bench['lbl']); ?></label> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
      }
    ?>
```

I am displaying the values of the above with the following function:

```
function doneBenchSelection() {
  try {
    var benchSno = $("input[type=radio][name=b_sno]:checked").val();
    $("#benchSno").val(benchSno);
    $("#obj_lst").html("Selected Bench Label: "+$("input[type=radio][name=b_sno]:checked").text());
  } catch(e) {
    alert(e.message);
  }
}
```

I want to get the `alt="some text"` text from the selected radio button:

```
 $("#obj_lst").html("Selected Bench Label: "+$("input[type=radio][name=b_sno]:checked").text());
```

Is it the correct and recommended way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the attribute value of any element you can use [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1) method or you can also use [.prop](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prop.asp) method

Try below code :

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').attr('alt');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [attr](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) function

```
   $('input[type="radio"]:checked').attr('alt');
```

with a loop if you have multiple radio buttons with different names:

```
labels = [];
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
 labels.push($(this).attr('alt'));
});
```

Comment: Whats the logic behind suggesting loop? When only one radio can be checked at one point

Comment: @Satpal oops didn't know he had the same name for the radio butons :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.attr(attributeName )`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr1)

```
var alt = $("input[type=radio][name=b_sno]:checked").attr('alt')
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `attr` function is useful to get attribute value on any element.

```
$("input[type=radio][name=b_sno]:checked").attr("alt");
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

You can get any attributes(value, alt, id, class or any custom) of input type by using

**$this("anySelector").attr(attribute Name Of input);**

```
var getAtlValue = $("input[type=radio]:checked").attr('alt');
```